# How to display markdown output in databricks notebook from a python cell

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-notebook

With IPython/Jupyter it's possible to output markdown using the [IPython display module and its `MarkDown`class](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.Markdown).

[image: Example markdown output]

## Question

How can I accomplish this with Azure Databricks?

## What I tried

#### Databricks `display`

Tried using Databrick's display with the IPython Markdown class:

```py
from IPython.display import Markdown
display(Markdown('*some markdown* test'))
```

but this results in the following error:

```
Exception: Cannot call display(<class 'IPython.core.display.Markdown'>)
```

#### IPython `display`

I then tried to use IPython's `display`:

```py
from IPython.display import display, Markdown
display(Markdown('*some markdown* test'))
```

but this just displays the text:

```
<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>
```

[image: Example failed ouput]

#### IPython `display_markdown`

Tried using IPython's `display_markdown`:

```py
from IPython.display import display_markdown
display_markdown('# Markdown is here!\n*some markdown*\n- and\n- some\n- more')
```

but this results in nothing showing up:

[image: Failed display_markdown]

#### Looking up documentation

Also tried checking Azure Databricks documentation. At first I visited https://www.databricks.com/databricks-documentation which leads me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/azure/databricks/ but I wasn't able to find anything via searching or clicking the links and I usually find Microsoft documentation quite good.

#### Checking Databrick's `display` source

As Saideep Arikontham mentioned in the comments, Databricks version 11 and above is using IPython kernel so I dug a bit deeper.

According to Databrick's source for the `display` function, it will readily render any object that implements `_repr_html()`.

[image: Databricks display]

However I'm having a hard time being able to get the raw html output that I'm assuming `IPython.display.Markdown` should be able to output. I can only find `_repr_markdown_()` and `_data_and_metadata()` [where the former just calls the latter](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/9fba0f5afea7bf015b44899c53425719927b3a7a/IPython/core/display.py#L436) and the output, at least in Databricks, is just the original raw markdown string.

Comment: Thanks for that @SaideepArikontham. As a result of your comment I dug a little deeper and updated my question. There must be a way to use one of IPython's module to generate the raw markdown html that I can wrap with an object and have that returned via `_repr_html_()`.

Comment: I couldn't find an IPython module so that we get the required output returned via `_repr_html_()` from `Markdown` class. However, I was able to get required output by writing my own `Markdown` class with help of another Python library. Will provide that as a solution if it will suffice your requirement.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham that would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Markdown` and `display_markdown` are not giving desired output when used in Azure Databricks. I have done the following in Databricks 11.1 runtime.

- Taking inputs from the question, I understood that when a class has `_repr_html()`, it is able to output the desired result. But when this method is absent in class, it is returning an object.
- So, for `Markdown` to work, I have written my own `Markdown` class where I used **Python's `markdown` library**.

```
from IPython.display import DisplayObject, TextDisplayObject

class Markdown(TextDisplayObject):

    def __init__(self,TextDisplayObject):
        import markdown as md
        
        #converting markdown to html
        self.html = md.markdown(TextDisplayObject)
        
    
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return self.html
```

- Now, this class is not completely same as the `IPython.display.Markdown`. I have formatted your sample markdown
  `'# Markdown is here!\n*some markdown*\n- and\n- some\n- more'` as following to get the desired result.

```
Markdown('''# Markdown is here!\n
*some markdown*\n
- and\n
- some\n
- more''')
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- For `display_markdown()` to display output, we must specify another argument raw as `True` (display_markdown(<markdown_str>, raw=True)). However, in Databricks it is returning undefined (NoneType).
- Please do install markdown library first using `%pip install markdown` in Databricks cell.